# Can Azure CosmosDB store non-ASCII characters to support multilingual data storage?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Customers save their information in native language in the write storage. I have a requirement to build a read storage for Customer information with basic attributes.  The customer names can be in English, Japanese, Chinese, Hindi, etc ...

1. Does the CosmosDB has the capability to store non-ascii characters as sql server?
2. Is it possible to query as follows:

   ```
   SELECT f.address
   FROM Families f
   WHERE f.id = 'アンダーソン家族'
   ```
3. If #1,2 are possible does all Api's for azure cosmosdb support this feature?
4. If cosmosdb does not support this storage what are other alternatives?

Please point to some documentation or blogs for building the document store which stores multilingual data in Azure CosmosDB.

Comment: well, have you tried to create and query such document?

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB supports utf-8 encoding for all features in the SQL API, including query.

Here's a test for Cosmos DB's JavaScript SDK which uses "डेटाबेस پایگاه داده 数据库" as a test expression. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/master/src/test/integration/encoding.spec.ts